# Highcharts dual X axis chart not scaling axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a dual x axis chart with `Hightcharts` so that I can map two series over each other. But I am stuck as the series come with different interval data. The series are:

```
Flow Rate - taken every 15 mins. - 96 data points, wanted as line chart
Usage - taken every hour. - 24 data points, wanted as bar chart
```

I have been playing [with this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/5sg9zeo0/) trying to make it work, but I keep finding the 15 min interval series does not get fully added to the chart as the hourly.

Or using the `linkedTo` property, I only get half the chart having bars.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Here's my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Usage Vs Flow Rate Example'
  },
  xAxis: [{
    categories: ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'],
    crosshair: true,
    width: '100%',
  }, {
    categories: ['00:00', '00:15', '00:30', '00:45', '01:00', '01:15', '01:30', '01:45', '02:00', '02:15', '02:30', '02:45', '03:00', '03:15', '03:30', '03:45', '04:00', '04:15', '04:30', '04:45', '05:00', '05:15', '05:30', '05:45', '06:00', '06:15', '06:30', '06:45', '07:00', '07:15', '07:30', '07:45', '08:00', '08:15', '08:30', '08:45', '09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00', '11:15', '11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '12:30', '12:45', '13:00', '13:15', '13:30', '13:45', '14:00', '14:15', '14:30', '14:45', '15:00', '15:15', '15:30', '15:45', '16:00', '16:15', '16:30', '16:45', '17:00', '17:15', '17:30', '17:45', '18:00', '18:15', '18:30', '18:45', '19:00', '19:15', '19:30', '19:45', '20:00', '20:15', '20:30', '20:45', '21:00', '21:15', '21:30', '21:45', '22:00', '22:15', '22:30', '22:45', '23:00', '23:15', '23:30', '23:45'],
    opposite: true,
    crosshair: true,
    width: '100%',
  }],
  yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value} L/m',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Flow Rate',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: 'Usage',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} L',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: false
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    x: 120,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 10,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || // theme
      'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Usage',
    type: 'column',
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [84,66,54,39,99,84,17,38,63,35,5,48,91,66,98,21,23,57,35,21,23,83,58,89],
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' L'
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Flow Rate',
    type: 'line',
    data: [10,2,3,1,2,2,1,10,1,3,1,2,2,1,10,2,9,4,9,4,8,8,3,1,8,7,6,1,4,3,9,1,9,2,8,1,10,5,6,6,9,9,5,3,1,10,8,2,1,5,8,4,6,9,5,9,10,6,5,8,4,10,8,2,1,6,8,3,9,6,1,6,1,1,10,3,10,9,1,8,8,4,1,2,6,5,7,9,7,5,4,9,10,7,7,5],
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' L/m'
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: The 15min interval is applied but there is not enough space to display each interval. In your fiddle use the menu "View in full screen" and you can see that all 15 min intervall are displayed. So you just need to grow the width of your container or play with margin part of chart

Comment: But I want the chart to have both series occupying the same width, so that the 4 points per hour on the line overlaps the 1 point bard chart and so they are visibly related. Not sure I understood your suggestion

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question. If you want align the two x axis, i think you need pass the x values in the data (perhaps as timestamp value) and not use categories on the axis and perhaps set min and max of x Axis to align them

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` features to achieve a wanted result?

Here is a simplified demo of my idea: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fesnwyp0/

```
  xAxis: [{
    type: 'datetime',
    crosshair: true,
  }, {
    type: 'datetime',
    opposite: true,
    crosshair: true,
  }],
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart